# How to Use Regression to look for difference in cost or rate between groups

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I work in advertising, and I've been tasked with analyzing cost per sale between groups. More specifically, I've been tasked with using a regression model to assess differences between the groups. The problem is that none of the models I can think of seem to make much sense. See below simulated data, and attempted models. Is there another way of organizing this data that might make more statistical sense? I realize that the data points are dates and so therefore violate some assumptions of independence, but i've been instructed to ignore this for now. I've also been instructed to use a no-intercept model, and interaction-only terms for group designation in the applicable model.

```
set.seed(1234)

## Simulate Data
date_seq=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2000/2/1"), by = "day")
group_a_spend=rpois(32,1050)
group_b_spend=rpois(32,900)
group_c_spend=rpois(32,1000)
group_d_spend=rpois(32,1100)
group_a_sales=rpois(32,150)
group_b_sales=rpois(32,90)
group_c_sales=rpois(32,75)
group_d_sales=rpois(32,50)  

## Data setup 1
campaign_df_1=data.frame(
date_seq,
group_a_spend,
group_b_spend,
group_c_spend,
group_d_spend,
group_a_sales,
group_b_sales,
group_c_sales,
group_d_sales
)

campaign_df_1$total_sales=campaign_df_1$group_a_sales+campaign_df_1$group_b_sales+campaign_df_1$group_c_sales+campaign_df_1$group_d_sales

## Data Setup 2
all_spend=c(group_a_spend,
group_b_spend,
group_c_spend,
group_d_spend)
all_sales=c(group_a_sales,
group_b_sales,
group_c_sales,
group_d_sales)
group_designation=c(
rep('a',32),  
rep('b',32), 
rep('c',32), 
rep('d',32)
)
campaign_df_2=data.frame(
rep(date_seq,4), group_designation,all_spend,all_sales
)


## Model with Data Setup 1 


mod1=lm(total_sales~0+group_a_spend+
group_b_spend+
group_c_spend+
group_d_spend, data = campaign_df_1)
summary(mod1)


## Moel with Data Setup 2

mod2=lm(all_sales~0+all_spend:group_designation, data = campaign_df_2)
summary(mod2)
```